# Why is the result different to what I expect?

Tags: javascript

**Initial understanding:**
I read somewhere that when referential data-types (objects) are assigned to a variableA, the variable contains the address of the memory of the object. And when variableA is assigned to variableB, variableB also gets a copy of this address in memory. I.e. it refers to the same object. I liked this definition.

```js
a = {color: "red"};

b = a;

//a = {color: "red"};

console.log(a);
console.log(b); 
console.log(a === b);
```

Looking at the snippet above confirms this idea. It looks like a copy of the address of the memory of the object that `a` references is stored in `a`. When `a` is assigned to `b`, `b` gets this 'address' and references the same object.

However, this falls apart when `a` is reinitialised (`a = {color: "red"};`):

```js
a = {color: "red"};

b = a;

a = {color: "red"};

console.log(a);
console.log(b); 
console.log(a === b);
```

I expected `a === b` to still return `true`. To me this contradicts my 'initial understanding' because surely if `b` got given the same address in memory that `a` is a 'label' to, `b` would 'update' and be a label of the same thing that `a` is a label of.

How do I revise my understanding of what's going on?

Comment: `a = {color: "red"};` creates a brand new object on the right side of the `=` and assigns a reference to that brand new object to `a`.  The new object is clearly not the same object as the old object. Every object initializer expression creates a unique new object.

Comment: @Pointy Have a look at my 'potential revised understanding'. I know the new object of `a` is not the same as the old object of `a`. ( I hope that's what it means for `a` to be 're-initialised'!) My question was if `b` would 'catch up' and still be the label of the thing that `a` is a label of.

Comment: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/comparing-objects-in-javascript-ce2dc1f3de7f Here's a good read for what you're asking.

Comment: you explained it yourself. b = a; copies the memory address, not the object. so when you create a new a obj, its going to be in a new memory location.

Comment: @tonitone120 no - the assignment to `b` results in **no long term relationship** between the two variables. The reference is assigned, and that's that.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy I think it's hammering home a bit now. I would be satisfied if I could describe the situation as: `b = a` means `b` is storing the exact address in memory that `a` has captured - *at that current moment*. There is no long-term relationship between the two variables. `a` is free to be reinitialised and point to a different memory location; meanwhile, `b` will still point to the old one. As long as something is referencing that old location, it will persist.

Answer (score 4):

First you create an object `{color: "red"}` and you set a reference from `a` on it.
Than you let `b=a`, by this the reference from a is copied to b, so both reference on the same object.
Third you create a completly new object `{color: "red"}` and set a reference for `a`on it. So now a has a new reference on it, but b still has the old one..
If you now compare `a===b` there will be looked if the references are identical and they are not so it's false.

Comment: +1 for                                                                                                 "*the reference is copied*". It's not a reference to `a`.

Answer (score 0):

From [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) about object equality, you can see this:

---

`Object.is()` determines whether two values are the same value. Two values are the same if one of the following holds:

- both undefined
- both null
- both true or both false
- both strings of the same length with the same characters in the same order
- **both the same object (means both object have same reference)**
- both numbers and

  - both +0
  - both -0
  - both NaN
  - or both non-zero and both not NaN and both have the same value

[...]
This is also not the same as being equal according to the === operator. **The === operator (and the == operator as well) treats the number values -0 and +0 as equal and treats Number.NaN as not equal to NaN**

---

In the case you posted, the highlighted condition fails, as the new assignment creates a new [complex] object: though the values between the instances are the same, their *identities* are not.

The goal of this quote is to illustrate object comparison in JS by different means, as it's clear in the questions that that's the key point asked by the user.

Comment: Just to clarify: you're not directly using `Object.is()`, but it illustrates how JS evaluates the object equality.

Comment: bottom line, you don't really want to use == to determine if objects are similar.

Comment: It's unclear why you're quoting documentation of `Object.is` when the OP is using `===`?

Comment: I said in my first comment: to illustrate the point of reference equality. The documentation also clarifies differences with `===`

Answer (score 0):

When you write `b = a`, you declare that you can call `a` object either `a` or `b`. In other words, you give a second name to `a`, that is `b`.

If you assign `a` to a new object (by opening key brackets `{}`), `a` is no longer the same object as `b`, they have different beginnings and identities.

If you want to compare objects by their content, you can do the next:

```js
var a = { color: 'red' };
var b = { color: 'red' };
console.log( JSON.stringify(a) );
console.log( JSON.stringify(b) );

Object.prototype.equals_obj = function(second) {
  return JSON.stringify(this) == JSON.stringify(second);
}

console.log( a.equals_obj(b) );
```